# Isomorphic Fields example

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I am trying to show $\mathbb Q(2+\sqrt{2})$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2})$. Specifically, I have difficulty showing the first is contained in the latter. I must be missing something easy but I cannot seem to find a similar question that has been asked before.

Answer (score 0):

If $\alpha$ is algebraic of degree two over $\mathbb Q$, then $\mathbb Q(\alpha) =\{a+b\alpha \colon (a,b) \in \mathbb Q\}$. From there it is easy to prove that $\mathbb Q(2+\sqrt{2}) =\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2})$.

Comment: To prove the two sets are equal, I thought you have to show there are subsets of each other?

Comment: Yes. Can you try to do it from the definition of $\mathbb Q(\alpha)$ I provided in the answer?

Comment: Can we take take b =0 to show they are equal sets?

Comment: Take any element of $\mathbb Q(2+\sqrt{2})$, try to write it as an element of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2})$ and vice versa.

Comment: Does $\mathbb Q(2+\sqrt{2}) =\{a+2b+b\sqrt{2} \colon (a,b) \in \mathbb Q\}$? So that $a+2b \in \mathbb Q$ and $b \in \mathbb Q$ implies the desired result

Comment: Yes that is right.